# R Markdown. "Error in eval, object not found"

Tags: r, markdown, eval

probably something simple i missed. Can someone please help. its for a Uni assignment.

I get this error:
*"Quitting from lines 24-46 (Ass2_V3.Rmd)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
object 'state.co2e.emissions.per.capita' not found
Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted"*

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library (gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(tidyverse)

emissions <- state.co2e.emissions.per.capita
emissions <- read.csv('//Users/garysinclairtactilemacbook/Desktop/RMIT_Data_Vis/Assignment 2/state-co2e-emissions-per-capita.csv')
attach(emissions)
names(emissions)[3]<- "CO2e.Emissions.tpc"
str(emissions)
head(emissions)



emissions = emissions %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ round(., digits = 2)))
head(emissions)

colSums(is.na(emissions))
```

Comment: In the line `emissions <- state.co2e.emissions.per.capita`, where does the value of ` `state.co2e.emissions.per.capita` come from? Why are you assigning to `emissions` just to reassign something else on the next line? You should really avoid `attach()`, that's considered a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks. MrFlick. I keep getting the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'state.co2e.emissions.per.capita' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval"

Which from what ive read means the R Markdown file cannot find the dataset>

Comment: Have you remove the line `emissions <- state.co2e.emissions.per.capita`? It is not helpfull if you only repeat the error we already know, but don't tell us what you done to avoid the error.  The line tries to access data that does not exist. Perhaps it was meant to be a comment. In the line below you read a CSV-file into `emission`. If you want @MrFlick to be notfied, prepend his name with an @ character. (like I did in this sentence), Btw: `attach` is not the problem, but it is not necessary and could lead to other problems, so do not use it in an R script.